# Let consider the sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that, $x_{n+1}= a^{\frac{x_n}{a}}$ where $x_1= a^{\frac{1}{a}}$ and $a$ is an natural number greater than 1.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let consider the sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $x_{n+1}= a^{\frac{x_n}{a}}$ where $x_1= a^{\frac{1}{a}}$ and $a$ is an natural number greater than 1.  I have seen that the sequence is increasing, but is convergent?

Comment: @joshua Yes. And that equation has 2 solutions.

Comment: Why is usefull?